# I cannot figure out how to grab input from EditText to pass to another file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext

I have a user type in information such as a UPC in the EditText box and then click a button next to it. How can I get the text from the box to pass to my other activity when they click the button? I'm assuming I use an Intent to launch the activity.

The edit text element:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Code for  search button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onClickSearch"
    android:text="@string/search" />
```

Code in main.java:

```
public void onClickSearch(View view) { 

        String UPC = R.id.editText1.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent("net.example.glutefree.Networking");   
        intent.putExtra("UPCA", UPC);  //text is some key used to retrieve value in NextActivity 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

If you need anymore code let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you were off to a good start, the important parts are to:

1) Get a reference to the EditText object in your activity code:

```
private EditText mMyEditText;
```

which should be initialized during onCreate like this:

```
mMyEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

2) Handle the click:

```
public void onClickSearch(View view) { 

    //String UPC = R.id.editText1.getText().toString(); 
    String UPC = mMyEditText.getText().toString();
    //Intent intent = new Intent("net.example.glutefree.Networking");   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourOtherClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("UPCA", UPC);  //text is some key used to retrieve value in NextActivity 
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The difference is that you were calling `getText` on an Identifier: **R.id.editText1**, which is an `int`, where now, you will be accessing the actual instance of an `EditText`.

Comment: is one worked perfectly! If I had the score I would "upvote" everyone for the amazing amount of help!

Answer (score 1):

You assume correctly. This is basically how you do it depending on exactly what you have and need. But you really should read [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
String et = editText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);   
intent.putExtra("text", et);  //text is some key used to retrieve value in NextActivity 
startActivity(intent);
```

`R.id.editText1` returns an `int`, which is the reason for your error. Try something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.name_of_your_layout);
     EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}
```

then use the code I provided originally. You have to `inflate` the `layout` using `setContentView()` then create a variable, `editText` here, you might want to declare it at the class level. Then initialize it to the `id` you set in your xml. The way you have it, you are trying to call `getText()` on the `int` which is what is returned by `R.id.some_id`. Once you have the variable and cast it to `EditText` with `(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` then you can call `getText()` on that variable.

Also note that you have to call `setContentView()` as I have shown before trying to access a `View` in that xml or you will get a `NPE` when you try to use the variable created from the xml since the `View`, `EditText` here, exists in the `layout`

Comment: I get an error saying Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type 
 int

Comment: This is why you need to post your code. This is generally how it would be done but we have no idea what is in your code